# FORMAS DE INSERTAR EN MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo la siguiente pregunta es que necesito agregar 1000 datos a una tabla pero no tengo mucho tiempo para hacerlo manualmente, estoy usando MYSQL

yo solo se lo básico mi pregunta es hay alguna manera de construir un ciclo que ejecute el INSERT INTO las 1000 veces que yo necesito estaba pensando en usar un ciclo WHILE no se si sea la mejor opción que me puedan aconsejar

```
delimiter $$
CREATE procedure ej()
  begin
    define i int;  
    set i = 1;
    while i<=1000 do
      INSERT INTO registro (nombre, apellido , edad,pais,telefono,) VALUES ('juan','garcia','21','colombia',31158794 i);
      set i=i+1;
    end while;
  end$$
```

e intentado de esta manera mas no se si sea correcta ya que son 1000 datos iguales

Comment: vale voy a tratar de ser mas espefico

Comment: Procura no usar mayúsculas sostenidas. De veras que es innecesaro y se recibe como gritos. Y pues, por ejemplo, puedes tener varias tuplas en VALUES (1,2,3,4,5), (6,7,8,9,0), (a,e,i,o,u),... y eso la BD lo procesa más rápido que una transacción con sólo una tupla en el INSERT. Ahí te ahorras tiempo. (200 INSERT con 5 tuplas son más rápidos que 1000 insert de una tupla). También puedes ver si desactivas índices antes de insertar y los activas al terminar; eso ahorra tiempo. Y así.

Comment: Sobre si es correcta, dinos tú si te da errores o no. Si no da errores y ves en la tabla lo que querías, es correcta (digo yo). Y consejos, consejos, aquí no se dan. Correcciones de errores, esas seguro sí las recibes aquí :)

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda, tendre en cuenta para futuras preguntas

Comment: los datos que vas a insertar salen de otra tabla?

Comment: Tenlo en cuenta ya para la pregunta actual ;) Lee [ask] y dale un título _específico_ a tu pregunta.

Comment: @juandavidtabordagarcia hola, podrias decir si la respuesta dada te resulto util, gracias

Answer (score 0):

En caso de que los datos a insertar en la tabla salgan de otra tabla puedes usar este código:

```
insert into registro (nombre, apellido, edad, pais, telefono)
select nombre, apellido, edad, pais, telefono
from OtraTabla
where ...;
```

Insertarás en la **tabla registro** la selección que hagas en tu consulta hacia la tabla de donde sacarás los registros que te hagan falta. De esta forma no te hace falta ningún ciclo ni nada ¨extraordinario¨ ya que todo se hace a través de sintaxis SQL.